Fast preload of woocommerce store or exclude data from cache
I have a woocommerce store with 15.000 products. Every night, I update all products via importing XML files from the manufacturer's websites to apply any changes in prices and availability. The problem with that is that every night the cache is cleared as the products are updated so there is no way to preload all products again until the next night. I haven't found any solution on that yet.
What I have done so far is to limit the products preloaded per minute to 10 (I discovered that this number doesn't cause any problem) but there is no so much time to preload all 15.000 until the next update. I have used the Redis both in the server and wordpress installation but didn't see any changes concerning the loading seed that I am targeting. What I am thinking as a solution but don't know how this can be one, is to exclude somehow the price and availability from the caching data and instead of loading them in the html, somehow to get them dynamically. I don't know if that make sense at all. Any suggestions would be very appreciated. thank guys.
